# Get the color on openstreetmap (OSM) of a perticular location using latitude and longitude using python

Tags: python, colors, openstreetmap

I am trying to find the colour of particular lat, long on OSM. I am unable to find any particular method in python to get the colour shown on OSM for particular lat, long. Basically I want to write a program for determining a location (lat, long ) on OSM is a river or not?

Comment: OpenStreetMap is a database of geographic information. You don't have to look at rendered raster tiles. Instead take a look at the raw data for determining whether a particular location is inside a water body.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please explain that what is the method to get the raw data from osm for determining whether a particular location is inside a water body?  It will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and the web frontend [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). See an [example for retrieving water elements](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/UZW). Also try to get familiar with OSM's [water features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Water) and their corresponding [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag).